# Sumar días a una fecha actual en javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, datepicker

Me encuentro trabajando con javascript, en este caso dentro mi input obtengo la fecha actual sin seleccionarlo dentro del datapicker.

Esta es mi vista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo para esta fecha actual, me solicitan que le sume 45 días para obtener la fecha de vencimiento.

Esto es lo que tengo realizado:

```js
function sumarDias(fecha, dias) {
            fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + dias);
            return fecha;
        }
        var x = new Date();
        document.getElementById("Fechadereservacion").value = x.toJSON().slice(0, 10);

        x.addEventListener("change", function () {

            var d = new Date(x.value);
            var y = document.getElementById("FechaCierre");
            y.value = sumarDias(d, 45).toISOString().substring(0, 10);
        });
```

```html
<input type="date" id="Fechadereservacion" name="Fechadereservacion">

<input type="date" id="FechaCierre" name="FechaCierre">
```

Mi incoveniente es que en esta parte:

```
 x.addEventListener("change", function () {

        var d = new Date(x.value);
        var y = document.getElementById("FechaCierre");
        y.value = sumarDias(d, 45).toISOString().substring(0, 10);
    });
```

No me da la suma de los días. Les agradecería de sus amables comentarios.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Te está dando algún error? ¿Te da un resultado inesperado? Pulsá en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta. Incluso podés agregar un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`) para crear un [repro] en la pregunta misma.

Comment: Que tal @padaleiana, No me muestra error alguno, solo que no hace la suma y por lo tanto me muestra la fecha de vencimiento que debe ser.

Answer (score 0):

yo utilicé 3 funciones para sumarDias, ya que por conveniencia en obtener los formatos de la fecha, pero bien los puedes hacer en una sola función.

Nota, ya solo agregas el resultado al input

```js
/*Funcion que va a sumar los días a una fecha formato "YYYY-mm-dd"*/
function sumarDias(fecha, dias){
    fecha = new Date(fecha);
    fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + dias);

    fecha = formatDate(fecha);
    return fecha;
}

/*Genera la fecha en formato "YYYY-mm-dd"*/
function formatDate(date) {
  return [
    date.getFullYear(),
    padTo2Digits(date.getMonth() + 1),
    padTo2Digits(date.getDate()),
  ].join('-');
}
/*Funcion para poner 2 digitos a un numero de un solo digito, ejemplo: 01*/
function padTo2Digits(num) {
  return num.toString().padStart(2, '0');
}

console.log(sumarDias('2022-07-27',45));
```

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a lo que pregunte, revise varias alternativas para poder solucionar el tema de las fechas. En este caso use el siguiente script:

```js
function sumarDias(fecha, dias) {
            fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + dias);
            return fecha;
        }
        FechaReservacion.valueAsDate = new Date();
            var d = new Date(FechaReservacion.value);
            var y = document.getElementById("FechaVencimiento");
                  y.value = sumarDias(d, 45).toISOString().substring(0, 10);
```

```html
<input type="date" id="FechaReservacion" name="FechaReservacion" , class="form-control">

<input type="date" id="FechaVencimiento" name="FechaVencimiento" class="form-control">
```

Lo siguiente que hice fue:

Mi input de FechaReservacion para obtener la fecha actual, use:

```
FechaReservacion.valueAsDate = new Date();
```

Una vez obteniendo mi resultado, de lo que ya tenía realizado en el query que adjunte en mi pregunta, use la parte en la que realiza la suma. Por lo tanto al aplicar esta forma, estoy obteniendo la fecha actual y la fecha de cierre o vencimiento aplicando la suma de los 45 días que en este caso el tiempo que me solicitaron.

Por lo que no se si es una buena practica o no, pero si alguien tendría la misma pregunta, este pequeño fragmento lo podría utilizar y poder mejorarlo de acuerdo a los requerimientos que tuviese.

De antemano agradezco los comentarios que me proporcionaron amablemente.

Saludos.